# Lightning nodes - two nodes on same network

Tags: networking, lightning

I want to have an Umbrel LND Lightning node on one machine and another one lnd node on windows 11 node on different machine BUT both machines are connected to same internet network

Both nodes have its own Bitcoincore full node running and synchronised and nodes are working OK

What I would like now is to connect the two nodes to do some testing - lightning learning

It seem to be impossible I get an unknown SOCKET error

I have to do port-forwarding or change ports on one of machines?

Umbrel node is as follows :

```
03a4201fc91e43c140c50a95a9ef55c84fa7039c733909318799c14c7a64c89231@5fk7orpfwzb6itowgl7usjp2wvtxf4rj4c5evnnspevruuqp5fswvkyd.onion:9735
```

Windows node is as follows :

```
0357a4cfc5da94397846ea7aa7c12fe726f97870d8fc665c5a047d1e81e0f82728@109.228.95.97:9735
```

I tried to connect them but not possible